# webpack and SystemJsNgModuleLoader at the same time Angular 5

Tags: angular, webpack, systemjs

Is it possible to use webpack and SystemJsNgModuleLoader at the same time in an Angular 5 web app?

I want to pack my main application (so that I only need to serve one file) and later dynamically load new modules (e.g. `DynModule` defined in `dyn.ts/js`) via SystemJsNgModuleLoader. As soon as I pack my app and try to dynamically load an NgModule it tells me, that it cannot find the module "./dyn".

> Update: Before bundling, my app does a webrequest and loads ./dyn.js. After bundling it does not do any webrequest.
>   I guess Webpack changes the behavior of my SystemJsNgModuleLoader. How can I get around this?

The following code does work if it is not packed:

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<button (click)="load()">load</button>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private loader: SystemJsNgModuleLoader) {
    }

    load() {
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.loader.load("./dyn")
                .then();
        });
    }
}
```

After packing my app with the following config, I get the following error:

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        filename: "./out.js"
    },
    entry: "./src/main.js",
}
```

Note: `dyn.ts/js` will not be included in my packed `out.js` since I load it dynamically.

```
out.js:51 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module "./dyn".

Error: Cannot find module "./dyn".
at eval (out.js:790)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
at Object.onInvoke (out.js:138)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
at Zone.run (zone.js:138)
at zone.js:872
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (out.js:138)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
at eval (out.js:790)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
at Object.onInvoke (out.js:138)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
at Zone.run (zone.js:138)
at zone.js:872
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (out.js:138)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
at zone.js:873
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (out.js:138)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
```

Assuming I can use webpack and SystemJsNgModuleLoader:

- What happens, if my `DynModule` imports something that is already imported by my `AppComponent`?
- And what happens, if my `DynModule` imports something that is not already imported by my `AppComponent`? What is SystemJs going to do?

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149016/load-new-modules-dynamically-in-run-time-with-angular-cli-angular-5/50395048#50395048](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149016/load-new-modules-dynamically-in-run-time-with-angular-cli-angular-5/50395048#50395048)